# How to clear security role in Sitecore?

Tags: c#, sitecore, roles

I am trying to remove a specific role from an item. Right now I have 3 role assigned. "Everyone", "sitecore\author", "sitecore\developer". How do I remove "Everyone" and "sitecore\author". So far I have tried this but it is not working.

```
public static void ClearSecurityRoles(this Item item)
{
    var accessrules = item.Security.GetAccessRules();
    var role = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.FromName("Everyone");
    accessrules.Helper.RemoveExactMatches(role,AccessRight.Any,PropagationType.Any);
    item.SaveSecurityAccessRules(accessrules);
}

public static void SaveSecurityAccessRules(this Item item, AccessRuleCollection accessRules)
{
    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    item.Security.SetAccessRules(accessRules);
    item.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

When I use `accessrules.clear()` it removes all the roles, but I want to be able to remove just two. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you post the raw value for the security field on the item?

Comment: When i try to get the raw view, i got the error "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out". Also, is there a way i can iterate over all the roles and remove by checking it role name?

Comment: The Everyone role is a virtual role. Sitecore provides a global Everyone role, The role is used when assigning and resolving security for all users, That's maybe why you can't remove  it, since its a virtual role

Comment: I tried removing another role but it still doesn't work.I tried to delete another name.

var role = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.Role.FromName(@"extranet\ SpecialContent");

Are my above methods correct? or is there a better way to remove a specific role?

Comment: And these roles are specifically applied on the item? not being inherited ?

Comment: i have a checkbox selection for security of item. If the checkbox is selected  and saved, it sets specific rule on that item, however when the checkbox is unchecked i have to remove that specific role which is why i am looking to remove just that role.

Comment: Finally was able to solve it. I fixed it by changing AccesRight.Any to AccessRight.ItemRead  and was also able to remove Everyone role.

Comment: @siddhipur You should add your comment above as a question answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
Role role = Role.FromName("Everyone");
AccessRuleCollection accessRules = item.Security.GetAccessRules();

foreach (var accessRight in _accessRights)
{
   AccessRight right = AccessRight.FromName(accessRight.Value);
   accessRules.Helper.RemoveExactMatches(role, right, PropagationType.Any);
}
item.Security.SetAccessRules(accessRules);
```